# C# deleting json field

Tags: c#, json, string, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "applicationCd"
            ],
            "query": "$applicationCd"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "entityStatusDesc"
            ],
            "query": "$entityStatusDesc"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "stepUserName"
            ],
            "query": "$stepUserName"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "model": {
              "query": "instance"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "instanceId": {
        "missing": "_last",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have json file and i just want to delete entire block inside must area due to given field name(applicationCd,EntityStatusDesc,StepUsername) .For example if given field is applicationCd  i want to delete that field entirely and my  json  should look like this.I will be grateful if anyone could help me.Thanks.

```
 {
      "from": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
           //deleted part
              "query_string": {
                "analyze_wildcard": true,
                "default_operator": "and",
                "fields": [
                  "entityStatusDesc"
                ],
                "query": "$entityStatusDesc"
              }
            },
   rest of the code is same
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I ask because that looks like an ElasticSearch query.

Comment: yeah it is,i am using query for search and  want to delete parts due to given keywords if they are empty.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to build the query based on the keywords you want to search for, rather than trying to delete them from the JSON after the fact?

Comment: Yes thats true but it's a company project and unfortunately i dont have permission to do.I have to manipulate query before method call.

Comment: Well, that's fun now, isn't it? I'd use JSON.NET to deserialize it into a `JObject`, and then drill down to the `must` array, and then find the item(s) you want to remove and remove them. Finally, you can serialize it back into JSON.